# Mysql：An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: mysql

I got this error massage in MySQL, it was not blocked by firewall/anti-virus software. It happened when some task which is resource-intensive was launched.

Someone mention that it may cause by process priority issue
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597

How can I do？

Error Msg：

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'xxx' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. 
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
       at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
       at SecureDockDataAccess.DBAccess.Execute(String sql)
```